# How to Deserialize JsonString to jsonformat in java

Tags: java, android, json

```
a:34:
{
s:2:\"id\";
i:14;
s:10:\"created_at\";
s:19:\"2017-02-20 17:09:01\";
s:10:\"updated_at\";
s:19:\"2017-11-01 08:30:43\";
s:11:\"id\";i:3;s:7:\"username\";
}
```

these is format i am getting, how to deserialize.
Any help thankyou

Comment: This is not in valid `JSON String format`.

Comment: your json format string is not valid , you can check this in this link : http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The google has a very good library for JSON serialization/deserialization, named 
[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

If you have a json string and you want to deserialize, you can do it simply by calling:

```
new Gson().fromJson(yourJsonString, Model.class);
```

where Model is the model class, where you can map your json string. If you check the library documentation, you can find more interesting things.